# C# File.Open a read-only file with FileMode.Create

Tags: c#, file, file-io, file-permissions

What I want to do is overwrite a read-only file. With a read/write file.

With read/write files if I use `File.Open(file, FileMode.Create)` then if the file exists then it is deleted and a new one is created. (Although I suspect that if it exists then it just opens the file and removes the contents, which is why it is unable to cope with files it encounters as read/write).

I have tried with different `FileAccess` enums, but none of them seem to help me (I keep getting a `UnauthorizedAccessException`).

The work around is that I just set the file as read/write before I try to `File.Open` and make a new file, is this the only way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: The documentation says that to open a file with Create you need the Write privilege. I don't see that throwing an exception is a bad thing, as I would rather .NET informed me that it was a read only file. Your workaround seems like a perfectly valid explicit solution to me.

Comment: Throwing the exception isn't a bad thing, but I just need to be able overwrite it every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the purpose of `ReadOnly`. It's to stop alterations to the file. What you're trying to do, is alter the file (in this case by overwriting it).

What I would imagine you would need to do, is set the file attribute:

```
File.SetAttributes(filePath, FileAttributes.Normal);
```

Before you write to the file.

Comment: As I said to @Frantisek, always thought I could delete a read-only file, just not alter its contents! :p Ah well, I figured the answer would be to remove the flag first. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a by design behavior. You can't write into a file that is readonly, thus you can't overwrite it either.

So the only and perfectly valid option is to remove the ReadOnly flag first.

Comment: Hmm, odd, because I can delete a read-only file from windows explorer without any issue! I always assumed that read-only was there to stop alterations, but not complete delete! Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Use FileInfo to change attributes of the file from ReadOnly (if you have permissions) and then overwrite the file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to remove the readonly attribute before writing it. Here there are some file utils to detect if a file is readonly and then to set non-readonly attribute.

```
    public static bool IsReadOnly(string file)
    {
        return (File.GetAttributes(file) & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) ==
                FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
    }

    public static void SetNonReadOnlyAttributes(string file)
    {
        try
        {
            FileAttributes attrs = File.GetAttributes(file);
            File.SetAttributes(file, attrs & ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(
                string.Format(
                    "Error setting non-readonly attributes to file {0}: {1}",
                    file, ex.Message));
        }
    }
```